# Java Program for coverting Json to Excel new

Tags: java

I was just converting Json file to excel. I am getting this error. Could anyone please help out. why does this error occurred.

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at character 1 of {
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:502)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:668)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:840)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromString(JSONObject.java:260)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:91)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:52)
    at javanewprog.ReadJson.main(ReadJson.java:40)
```

JSON:

```
{
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
          "Acronym": "SGML",
          "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": [
              "GML",
              "XML"
            ]
          },
          "GlossSee":"markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your JSON file is invalid. Please add the JSON file to your post.

Comment: You've added the error, now add your code and any other relevant pieces to make a simple executable example we can help debug for you.

Comment: I am unable add the code

Comment: its seems your json is wrong

Comment: {
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
  "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
   "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
     "SortAs": "SGML",
     "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
     "Acronym": "SGML",
     "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
     "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
      "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
     "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: this was the json file i used

Comment: I have changed the Json file now i am getting following error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at net.sf.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:389)
 at net.sf.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:501)
 at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:365)
 at net.sf.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:515)

Comment: @sathishkumar: What do you expect here? You are "unable" to add the code and simply fire the totally explanatory error message (_"A JSONObject text must end with '}'"_) and expect the community to solve your problem. Stackoverflow is for answering _programming questions_, not as a free support for whatever you are trying to achieve. Please take the [intro tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You JSon looks good (you can validate it [here](http://jsonlint.com/)).

On the other hand, you might be thinking that GlossSee and GlossSeeAlso are at the same level when they are not. GlossSee is at the same level as GlossDef.